# Passing dynamic values to table control for TreeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I am working on a web application in C# using ASP.NET 4.0. The requirement is I need to display hierarchical information for an organization. For example, a senior manager will have a manager under him/her, and a manager will have team leads, and each team lead will have employees under him/her. The same structure needs to be displayed in a TreeView. Every node in the TreeView will display the name of an employee and the count of records in the node (this count is populated from the database). The count data needs to be displayed in the table control under the corresponding node of the TreeView. If the count is three records, I need to display a table with three rows, which data fetched from the database, based on the selected node ID. This table should be under the node only. I have code which adds the table but I am not able to pass dynamic values to the query.

The following is the code:

```
public class TreeNodeEx : TreeNode
{
    protected override void RenderPostText(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString().Trim();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from TableA where Name='Krishna'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        Table table1 = new Table();

        int rows = 1;
        int cols = 5;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            TableRow r = new TableRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
            {
                TableCell c = new TableCell();
                c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][i].ToString()));
                r.Cells.Add(c);
            }
            table1.Rows.Add(r);
        }
        table1.RenderControl(writer);
        base.RenderPostText(writer);
    }
}
```

Code called under the nodes are:

```
TreeNodeEx n = new TreeNodeEx();    
parent.ChildNodes.Add(n);
```

This is the code to add count:

```
child.Text = dr["User_Given_Name"].ToString() + " [Records # (" + dsn.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + ")]"; child.Value = dr["User_Email"].ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: You can't just put the count in the node's caption? like, "John Doe (4)"

Comment: This is the code to add count:                                      child.Text = dr["User_Given_Name"].ToString() + "  [Records # (" + dsn.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() + ")]";
                child.Value = dr["User_Email"].ToString().Trim();